# Azure Site Recovery - Configuration Server

Tags: azure

I'm trying to follow the steps in [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure/).

I fill all the data and confirm. when will monitor progress on the Jobs tab it shows the failure:

"The operation was interrupted (error code: 548).."
 "Possible causes: The operation stopped because the limit of retries has been exceeded."

After trying again it shows:

"An internal error occurred (error code: 499).."
 "Possible causes: The operation failed due to an internal error."

Has anyone had this error and could solve or have any idea how I could solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary site and azure are no longer connected, that's when this kind of error pops up.
One possible reason as to why the process server gets disconnected is if the process server on your primary site has it's IP address changed for example. If so you will have correct it to the present one in the host config settings on the process server and the target servers as well and amethyst.conf ([ASR location]/svsytems/etc/amethyst.conf).